# Using Sourcetree client to store Maya files on Bitbucket repository

Tags: git, version-control, repository, maya, atlassian-sourcetree

I wanted to know if Sourcetree supports Maya files (whether binary or ASCII) versioning control, I haven't been able to find any topic about it.

If it can be done, I wanted to know what procedures do I have to follow, like in Unity, on which you have to set visible meta files of your version control mode and your assets serialization forced on text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not an expert in this subject but I'm interested too. My 2cents would be that you can store both binary and ASCII files in your repo but only `.ma`s will be properly diff-ed. I guess it all trace down to which kind of Maya scenes you want to store (ie. how big, how many, storing what kind of data) and if you need to granularly keep track of changes; basically, what you need depends on how you plan to use the files. I am not familiar with Unity, so I'm not sure what you're referring to: if you can post a link a might have a look at that to get a better idea

Comment: Text-based source control systems (git, svn, etc) will work with `.ma` files -- but the diffs are rarely useful since the ordering of the changes between two versions of the file is not always predictable. This tends to mean very big repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Git repo can version control for Maya files, but binary files in git repo will take large size (as the commits also mentioned).

So the better way is using **Git LFS with your Bitbucket repo together**. You can track the binary files in LFS, and your repo size will be balanced. Details about git LFS with bitbucket, you can refer [Use Git LFS with existing Bitbucket repositories](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-git-lfs-with-existing-bitbucket-repositories-829078749.html).

For viewing different versions of the Maya files, `git diff` won't show the different content separately, but you can checkout to a certain version (`git checkout commit`) to compare manually.